# Sharpgl can see a line parallel to the Z axis

Tags: c#, opengl, opengl-compat

I drew a line parallel to the Z axis in sharpgl. I set the camera above the Z axis, so I thought I would see 1 point, but I don't see it. Later I want to draw a large number of these lines side by side, now I'm trying on one.

Camera settings:

```
gl.Ortho (0, 1595, 0, 1000, -30, 80);

gl.LookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 90.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Line Drawing:

```
gl.LineWidth (100.0f);
gl.Begin (OpenGL.GL_LINES);
gl.Color (0, 0, 0);
gl.Vertex (600, 600, 30);
gl.Vertex (600, 600, 50);
gl.End ();
gl.Flush ();
```

When I draw a line at a different angle, you can see it:

```
gl.Vertex (180, 15, 20);
gl.Vertex (800, 800, 20);
```

When I draw only a point, I also see it:

```
gl.PointSize (100.0f);
gl.Begin (OpenGL.GL_POINTS);
gl.Color (0, 0, 0);
gl.Vertex (800, 800, 20);
gl.End ();
```

I need to see the line. Do I need to add a point to the beginning and end of a line, or is it just something to set the line to be visible?

Comment: How exactly do you expect to 'see the line'? If it's parallel to the z-axis in orthographic projection then the start and end points of the line coincide on the screen, so it has zero length -- thus nothing is drawn.

Comment: I want to see 1 point.

Comment: Then you'll need to draw it with `GL_POINTS` indeed. OpenGL won't do that automatically simply because it's not how it rasterizes lines.

Comment: Thanks for advice.